# PHP construct a Unicode string?

Tags: php, unicode

Given a Unicode decimal or hex number for a character that's wanting to be output from a CLI PHP script, how can PHP generate it? The `chr()` function seems to not generate the proper output. Here's my test script, using the Section Break character U+00A7 (A7 in hex, 167 in decimal, should be represented as C2 A7 in UTF-8) as a test:

```
<?php
echo "Section sign: ".chr(167)."\n"; // Using CHR function
echo "Section sign: ".chr(0xA7)."\n";
echo "Section sign: ".pack("c", 0xA7)."\n"; // Using pack function?
echo "Section sign: §\n"; // Copy and paste of the symbol into source code
```

The output I get (via a SSH session to the server) is:

```
Section sign: ?
Section sign: ?
Section sign: ?
Section sign: §
```

So, that proves that the terminal font I'm using has the Section Break character in it, and the SSH connection is sending it along successfully, but `chr()` isn't constructing it properly when constructing it from the code number.

If all I've got is the code number and not a copy/paste option, what options do I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has no knowledge of Unicode when excluding the mb_ functions and iconv. You'll have to UTF-8 encode the character yourself.

For that, Wikipedia has an [excellent overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) on how UTF-8 is structured. Here's a quick, dirty and untested function based on that article:

```
function codepointToUtf8($codepoint)
{
    if ($codepoint < 0x7F) // U+0000-U+007F - 1 byte
        return chr($codepoint);
    if ($codepoint < 0x7FF) // U+0080-U+07FF - 2 bytes
        return chr(0xC0 | ($codepoint >> 6)).chr(0x80 | ($codepoint & 0x3F);
    if ($codepoint < 0xFFFF) // U+0800-U+FFFF - 3 bytes
        return chr(0xE0 | ($codepoint >> 12)).chr(0x80 | (($codepoint >> 6) & 0x3F).chr(0x80 | ($codepoint & 0x3F);
    else // U+010000-U+10FFFF - 4 bytes
        return chr(0xF0 | ($codepoint >> 18)).chr(0x80 | ($codepoint >> 12) & 0x3F).chr(0x80 | (($codepoint >> 6) & 0x3F).chr(0x80 | ($codepoint & 0x3F);
}
```

Comment: An excellent way to do that would just be to write the PHP document in UTF-8 in the first place.

Comment: Excellent answer, Michael; and thanks for the function! I created something similar for myself using the pack function rather than chr repeatedly. Billy, for this specific purpose, I need to go from a codepoint to a character; writing the PHP script in UTF-8 with the characters already embedded isn't an option.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have `iconv`, here's a simple way that doesn't involve implementing UTF-8 yourself:

```
function unichr($i) {
    return iconv('UCS-4LE', 'UTF-8', pack('V', $i));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget that UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding.

`§` is not included in the first 128 (ASCII) characters that UTF-8 is able to display in *one* byte. `§` is a multi-byte character in UTF-8, prepended by a `c2` byte that signifies `first byte of a two-byte sequence.`. This should work:

```
echo "Section sign: ".chr(0xC2).chr(0xA7)."\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
chr

(PHP 4, PHP 5)

chr — Return a specific character

Report a bug
 Description

string chr ( int $ascii )
Returns a one-character string containing the character specified by ascii.
```

This function complements ord().

important is the word ascii :)
try this one:

```
  function uchr ($codes) {
        if (is_scalar($codes)) $codes= func_get_args();
        $str= '';
        foreach ($codes as $code) $str.= html_entity_decode('&#'.$code.';',ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');
        return $str;
    }
    echo "Section sign: ".uchr(167)."\n"; // Using CHR function
    echo "Section sign: ".uchr(0xA7)."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am reopening an old, solved issue, however since I stumbled into that topic searching for help, I thought I would share the solution I ended up with.
The initial person asking the question might be interested in refactoring his/her code for the best.

Manually reprogramming ascii-to-unicode is like reinventing the wheel, not talking about errors/performance potential.

The best solution I found was to use:

1. [`pack`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) to create values from input data, using the appropriate codes to eat the right amount of data, usually `pack("H*", <input data>)` to read from hexadecimal values
2. [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to convert ASCII strings to unicode ones, using `mb_convert_encoding(<ASCII string>, "UTF-8")`. If the input string is not recognized properly, a third parameter of this function allows to specify the input encoding